# What is collation_database, collation_connection, collation_server used for in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-connection, collation

```
Illegal mix of collations (big5_chinese_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

Sometimes this error is throw, what's up?
What's the `collation_*` used for?
Can someone give me an example to show how the character is encoded, transited and selected, relate to `collation_*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL,every table has a table character set and a table collation.

Collation is a set of rules on how to compare and sort character strings.

Every MySQL collation belongs to a single character set and every MySQL character set can have one or more collations which belong to it.

Mysql uses `binary_key` for sorting character sets, the new `weight_string` function available in MySQL 5.2 converts the character to-be compared to `binary_key`.

```
SELECT WEIGHT_STRING('a');
```

gives 0x41.

```
SELECT WEIGHT_STRING('A');
```

gives 0x41.

This **[pdf](http://forge.mysql.com/w/images/b/b7/HowToAddACollation.pdf)** from Mysqlwiki has examples for what you want!